# "New/Recently updated technology" tab?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've got a question about Xcode 4 and I've gone to post it on StackOverflow and then it hit me just how many Xcode 4 questions there are. Similar to every UI update on StackExchange, when something in the tech community changes, a barrage of new questions is generated.

***I propose that new technologies come out, questions on that topic be featured in a tab dedicated to new or recently update technologies.*** This way, people can see the latest questions on that topic. When Visual Studio or Xcode gets a new release, people have questions. When a new SDK is released, the same thing happens.

In practice, I think that this can be implemented in the following way:

The community should be able to mark a tag or tags as "new or recently updated". This way, appropriate questions will get exposure and there will be less dupes. Additionally, questions on new technologies are often interesting and can provide additional benefit, beyond regular questions. After several folks mark a tag as a new technology, it gets featured in the tab for X (amount of time). I would also suggest that you be required to have a minimum rep and some sort of indication that you are affiliated with that tag, be it a minimum number of questions, answers or rep from that tag.

Comment: I am SO HAPPY Xcode 4 is out!  Now we won't have apple devs flagging every Xcode 4 question screaming about the NDA!  Oh, also, I think this is a cool idea.